# after adding wallpaper manager package it showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Launching lib\main.dart on V2130 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\flutter\fluttersdk\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wallpaper_manager-1.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mulgundkar\wallpaper_manager\WallpaperManagerPlugin.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
String assetLookupKey = FlutterLoader.getInstance().getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath);
^
symbol:   method getInstance()
location: class FlutterLoader
C:\flutter\fluttersdk\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\wallpaper_manager-1.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mulgundkar\wallpaper_manager\WallpaperManagerPlugin.java:152: error: cannot find symbol
String assetLookupKey = FlutterLoader.getInstance().getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath);
^
symbol:   method getInstance()
location: class FlutterLoader
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':wallpaper_manager:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1